# htop: the CPU load of individual process is higher than the CPU load according to the CPU bar

Tags: linux, htop

[image]
I run a python network client (it actively downloads video through TCP) inside of VirtualBox (5.1.26) and the CPU load of this process is much higher (20%) than the CPU load according to the CPU bar in the left top corner. How is it possible?
It is not a rare event: the CPU load of this process is usually ~15-20% and CPU load according to the bar in the corner is usually ~3-5%.
The host machine has 4 physical cores (8 logical) and the guest system has 1 CPU. Both host and guest use Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

They are related, but the load average is not the same as the CPU usage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)